# What version of GDAL do I need to install to run alongside PostGIS?

Tags: gis, postgis, gdal

As the title states, I've downloaded the latest version of PostGIS from the official website: http://postgis.net/windows_downloads

My question is, how do I know which version of GDAL to install alongside this version of PostGIS? Would it just be the latest available version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostGIS now include the most recent compatible version of GDAL in their installation package. You don't need to download anything, just dive straight into the guide for setting up/configuring GDAL commands!

Here's a link to start you off.

https://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/gdal_quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks again, answered both my questions :)

Comment: Is there a good 'getting started to PostGIS' link as well you'd recommend?

Comment: This is the guide I first used to start me off!
http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01